# Find File System in Firmware

Tags: firmware

This is my first attempt at working with firmware. We have some SNMP cards that are flaky & my ultimate goal is to try to make them better.

The current firmware version is 12.06.0069. When downloaded, the firmware folder contains several files:

- `pwralert.dat`
- `rom.12.069.0001.3078.sbz2`
- `rom.55.0.bin`
- `rom.69.0.bin`
- `rom.69.0.bin.sbz2`

I've been trying to use `binwalk` to locate the filesystem. So far, the only thing I've found is a few lines that say "gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00). Here is how I got there:

```
binwalk -e rom.12.069.0001.3078.sbz2

cd _rom.12.069.0001.3078.sbz2.extracted

ls

418

binwalk 418
```

[image]

[image]